# Rerun a program using nested for loops

Tags: c#

I just started learning how to program in c #, so don't shoot me if I have "dumb" questions or questions to which the answer is probably very logical.

I have the next assignment:

Use a for loop to write the next pattern:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 30
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 40
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 50
51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 60
61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 70
71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 80
81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 90
91 92 93 94 95 96 97
```

It has to be possible for the user to set a maximum (in this example 97) and then rerun the application without restarting.

What I am trying now is this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string output = "", input = "";
        int MaxWaarde, karakters = 15;
        do
        {           
            Console.WriteLine("Gelieve het maximum van de matrix in te geven");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            MaxWaarde = Convert.ToInt32(input);

            for (int i = 1; i <= MaxWaarde; i += 11)
            {
                Console.Write(i);
                for (int j = i; j < MaxWaarde + 1; j += karakters)
                {
                    Console.Write(j);
                }                   
                Console.WriteLine(karakters + "");
            }             
            Console.Write("\nOpnieuw een matrix aanmaken? (y/n): ");
            output = Console.ReadLine();
        }           
        while (output.ToLower() == "y");
    }
}
```

Which isn't correct at all, but I have been trying to fix this for a while now, and I think I have been staring myself blind at this one, so i really don't know which way to go with this anymore.

Somebody who can give me some advice on how to make this right?

Comment: What happens when you run the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Loop1`: Count up from 1 to number by step 1. If number is a multiple of 10 it writes that number again with line feed.

`Loop2`: Do loop1 again as long user wishes.

Answer (score 1):

Nested for loops doesn't seem like a good idea here.You can do it with one `for` loop.You are incrementing `i` `+11` in every step,probably your mistake is here. Consider this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= MaxWaarde; i++)
{ 
    if(i % 10 != 0) Console.Write(i + " ");
    else
    {
       Console.Write(i + " " + i + "\n");
    }
}
```

`%` is [modulus operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx).We are looking for remainder of `currentNumber / 10`, if it's not zero we write the `number.`If it is then we write value twice and adding a [newline character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) with `\n` to go the next line.Also You can use `Console.WriteLine()` instead of `\n`

Comment: What you are saying is not what is needed here.

Comment: No,exacly what is needed.And this code producing the expected output.Read the question again.While loop is correct, I fixed his for loop

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            var val = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int i = 1; i <= val; i++)
            {
                if (i % 10 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {0}", i);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("{0} ", i);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```